# jquery 1.8.0 Syntax error, unrecognized expression: &gt;

Tags: javascript, jquery, web

I included jquery in my web page and face to this error of jquery 1.8.0 error:

```
Syntax error, unrecognized expression:  &gt;
```

someone help me

Comment: Without any code, we can't help you.

Comment: The problem could be an ajax call to an invalid url. But it's hard to say without some code.

Comment: @Thomas the error wouldn't be a Syntax error if that was the case. That would cause a 404/500 error and the ajax call would catch that differently.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm betting you are using a web framework that encodes HTML. When you are using the "child" selector in jQuery - "`>`" - your framework is probably converting that to "`&gt;`". That means the code in your IDE/editor looks like this:

```
$("#test > div")
```

but is converted to this:

```
$("#test &gt; div")
```

and sent to the browser. The jQuery library doesn't understand that, so it bombs.

This is very dependent on the framework you use, so can you let us know what you use?

I've used CherryPy in the past, and I know to get around this problem, you can use this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
    // Your code here
//]]>
</script>
```

Because your HTML page should technically be fully XML, the framework may attempt to encode anything that breaks that rule.

Answer (score 0):

I used `&('div &gt p')` in my code. and that was the problem.